# Best method to fit hyperplane using a rotation around a common vector?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, registration, plane

so I was curious about the best method to fit two hyperplanes with each other using a vector.

Let's say I have a plane pl1 composed of the points pa1, pb1 and pc1, while the plane pl2 is made using the points pa2, pb2 and pc2. I can get the rotations between the vectors made from the points (pa1, pb1) and (pa2, pb2) using Eigen. pa1 and pa2 are at coordinates (0,0,0).

```
const ::Eigen::Vector3d v1 = ((::Eigen::Vector3d) (pb1 - pa1)).normalized();
const ::Eigen::Vector3d v2 = ((::Eigen::Vector3d) (pb2 - pa2)).normalized();

::Eigen::Matrix3d rot1;
rot1 = ::Eigen::Quaterniond().setFromTwoVectors(v2, v1).toRotationMatrix();
const ::Eigen::Matrix4d t1 = ::Eigen::Affine3d(rot1).matrix();
```

And then, I want to rotate around v1 to register the planes. What would be the best way to find the angle alpha where the planes are on each other?

Once I get this angle, I can find the final transformation using:

```
::Eigen::Matrix4d t2 = ::Eigen::Affine3d(::Eigen::AngleAxisd(alpha, v1)).matrix();
::Eigen::Matrix4d t3 = t2 * t1;
```

But I'm stuck with the middle part, is there maybe an Eigen function to do that? :)

Comment: To understand things better: ```pa1``` and ```pa2``` are both at the origin ```(0,0,0)```. So both planes intersect each other at the origin and both are perfectly described by ```pb``` and ```pc``` respectively. You now want to find the rotation to transform the first plane into the second plane?

Comment: If so, the easiest way I can think of, is take the normal vectors of each plane: eg. cross product of ```pb1``` and ```pc1``` for the first normal vector. Then you only need to find the transformation of the first normal vector to the second one. If you need the angle between these two for that, you can calculate that with the scalar product of both normal vectors.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks, I will try that!